# Get return value of python builtin functions while tracing

Tags: python, debugging, profiling, trace

By using [sys.setprofile](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/sys.html#sys.setprofile)(profilefunc) I can trace not only regular Python functions, but also builtin ones via the events "c_call" and "c_return", but I cannot find a way to get the return value of a builtin function.

For a regular function, the parameter `arg`, which is passed to profilefunc, refers to the return value if `event` equals "return".
However, if `event` equals "c_return", `arg` is the C function object.

Is there another way to retrieve the return value of a builtin function? Maybe by extracting from the frame the last value what was returned?

Here is a minimal example:

```py
import sys
import numpy as np
from types import FrameType


def tracefunc(frame: FrameType, event: str, arg):
    if event == 'call':
        func_name = frame.f_code.co_name
        print(f'Call_to {func_name}')
    elif event == 'return':
        func_name = frame.f_code.co_name
        print(f'Return_from {func_name}, returning {arg}')
    elif event == 'c_call':
        func_name = arg.__name__
        print(f'Call_to_builtin {func_name}')
    elif event == 'c_return':
        func_name = arg.__name__
        print(f'Return_from_builtin {func_name}, returning ???')
    return tracefunc


if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.setprofile(tracefunc)
    # non-builtin function
    foo = [x + 1 for x in [1, 2]]
    # builtin function
    bar = np.random.uniform()
    sys.setprofile(None)
```

With the output

```
Call_to <listcomp>
Return_from <listcomp>, returning [2, 3]
Call_to_builtin uniform
Return_from_builtin uniform, returning ???
Call_to_builtin setprofile
```